# Como cambiar de contenido de endrawer dependiendo del context

Tags: flutter, dart

Como puedo cambiar el contenido de un endDrawer cuando se usa *onPressed: () => Scaffold.of(context).openEndDrawer(),*. Ya necesito que cambie de hijo widget dependiendo de donde este.

Ejemplo: ahorita esta para que cuando se llama el Scaffold.of(context).openEndDrawer() abre el endDrawer con el widget createpool(), pero ocupo que el widget createpool() cambie cuando se hace un onpress()

```
return Scaffold(
  drawer:_con.isMobile ? Drawer(child: _buildMenuMobile()) : Container(),
  endDrawer: SizedBox(
     width: _con.isMobile ? _width / 1.2 : _width / 3,
     child: const Drawer(elevation: 5, child: CreatePool()),
  ),
  backgroundColor: _theme.background,
  body: _con.isMobile ? _inMobile() : _inDesktop(),
);
```

Comment: hace unos años cree este post, dale una leída :  https://medium.com/comunidad-flutter/comunicaci%C3%B3n-entre-widgets-5f61b6c2e56c

Answer (score 0):

Ya probaste creando un stateful widget y creando una variable de control(flag) que cambie dependiendo de la situación. (si tienes más de una situación usa un enum).

Con ayuda del **setState** renderizas el widget que necesitas en el endDrawer.
Si requieres algo más sofisticado puedes usar provider o cubit para hacer lo mismo.

```
class TestingWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  TestingWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TestingWidget> createState() => _TestingWidgetState();
}

class _TestingWidgetState extends State<TestingWidget> {
  bool showCreatePool = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      drawer: _con.isMobile ? Drawer(child: _buildMenuMobile()) : Container(),
      endDrawer: SizedBox(
        width: _con.isMobile ? _width / 1.2 : _width / 3,
        child: const Drawer(
          elevation: 5,
          child: showCreatePool ? CreatePool() : INotACreatePoolWidget,
        ),
      ),
      backgroundColor: _theme.background,
      body: Container(
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            setState(() {
              showCreatePool = !showCreatePool;
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget get INotACreatePoolWidget => Text('I Not a create Pool');
}
```